# How to get the next n records in a django queryset?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get the next n records in django queryset?

For example, how would I get the next 5 records after getting the first five records? My use case is that I have a see more button on my page and I want to load the next 5 records whenever the see more button is clicked (via ajax)

I would like to do something like this

```
#function that handles ajax
def load_next_five(initial_five)
    next_five = initial_five.???
    return JsonResponse({'next_five': list(next_five)})

def main_view(request):
    initial_five = Car.objects.filter(year__gte=2000)
    ...
```

How would I go about the load_next_five function?

Comment: Look into pagination https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/. Django Rest Framework also offers some pagination tools which may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a slice.  You'll have to pass in where you want to start.

```
def load_next_five(start)
    next_five = Car.objects.filter(year__gte=2000)[start:start+5]
    return JsonResponse({'next_five': list(next_five)})

def main_view(request):
    initial_five = Car.objects.filter(year__gte=2000)[:5]
```

Under the covers, Django will turn that into clauses that will limit the results on the database side (for example, LIMIT and OFFSET).

Comment: Your rock! I didn't know this functionality existed in Django. Do you happen to have a link to the docs for the "start" slice?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries//  Look for the section on "Limiting Querysets"

Answer (score 1):

Follow the django paginator, easy to use.

```
def load_next_five(request):
    car_obj = Car.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(car_obj, 5) # change this number as you required
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        cars = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        cars = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        cars = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return JsonResponse({'cars': cars})
```